# How to solve CentOS 7 dependency problems when upgrading to PHP 7.2.3

Tags: centos7, upgrade, php7, dependencies

I am trying to upgrade PHP form 5.4.16 to 7.2.3 on a CentOS 7.4 server running HTTP 2.4.6.

I get these dependency alerts on this command:

`yum install php70w php70w-fpm php70w-cli php70w-common php70w-xml php70w-soap php70w-xmlrpc php70w-mbstring php70w-json php70w-gd php70w-mcrypt --skip-broken`

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    gd-last-2.2.5-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-safe
    libargon2-20161029-2.el7.x86_64 from epel
    php-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-cli-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-common-7.2.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-common-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-devel-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-fpm-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-gd-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-json-7.2.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-json-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-ldap-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-mbstring-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-mysqlnd-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-odbc-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-pdo-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-pecl-apcu-5.1.11-1.el7.remi.7.2.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.1-4.el7.remi.7.2.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-pecl-ssh2-1.1.2-1.el7.remi.7.2.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-process-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-soap-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-xml-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php-xmlrpc-7.2.3-2.el7.remi.x86_64 from remi-php72
    php70w-mcrypt-7.0.27-1.w7.x86_64 from webtatic
    php72w-common-7.2.2-1.w7.x86_64 from webtatic
```

Can someone assist me with how to revolve? Thank you.

Comment: Don't run that command. And don't follow whatever tutorial it appeared in. You already _have_ PHP 7.2.3 installed. And that command would have installed some other not very reliable build of PHP 7.0.

Comment: Don't run --skip-broken.